# how do I get the method immediately surrounding the caret position?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am quite new to Eclipse Plugin development so I need a bit of help.
I have a project in which I must get the current position of the cursor within an active editor and upon clicking a button, I am to display in a dialog box the method directly surrounding it. I have tried the following and I am so far only able to get the name of the method, but not the entire source code as I want. If I try only with compilationUnit I can also get the entire source code of the active editor. Other questions seem to only require the name of the method, but I'm interested in getting the full source code of the method. Is there any way I can get the source code of only the method directly surrounding the cursor?

```
    IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
    IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
    ITextEditor textEditor = (ITextEditor) page.getActiveEditor();
    IJavaElement element = JavaUI.getEditorInputJavaElement(textEditor.getEditorInput());
    if (element instanceof ICompilationUnit) {
        ITextSelection selection = (ITextSelection) ((JavaEditor) textEditor).getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
        IJavaElement selected;
        try {
            selected = ((ICompilationUnit) element).getElementAt(selection.getOffset());

            if (selected != null && selected.getElementType() == IJavaElement.METHOD) {
                return (IMethod) selected;
            }

            MessageDialog.openInformation(
                    window.getShell(),
                    editor.getTitle(), 
                    selected +"\n"); //(IMethod)
        } catch (JavaModelException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah so I found an answer. It took a while but I finally figured it out.

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);

    try {
        IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

        ISelection selection = workbenchWindow.getSelectionService().getSelection();
        ITextSelection textSelection;
        if (selection instanceof ITextSelection)
            textSelection = (ITextSelection) selection;
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("No text selection");

        IEditorInput editorInput = workbenchWindow.getActivePage().getActiveEditor().getEditorInput();
        ICompilationUnit compilationUnit = JavaUI.getWorkingCopyManager().getWorkingCopy(editorInput);
        IJavaElement elementWithCursorInside = compilationUnit.getElementAt(textSelection.getOffset());
        ISourceReference sourceReference;
        if (elementWithCursorInside instanceof ISourceReference)
            sourceReference = (ISourceReference) elementWithCursorInside;
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("Not an ISourceReference");

        MessageDialog.openInformation(window.getShell(), "Source Code of the Method", sourceReference.getSource());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
```

this seems to work well for me now. I hope maybe my solution will help someone else with the same problem